# Calling function from another website cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm making a Website using Visual Studio 2015. I have 2 classes, `Default:System.Web.UI.Page` and `Login:System.Web.UI.Page`. Both are partial classes.

I have a function called `returnUserType` from Login and I want to have it in Default so that if userType` is a certain number, the page redirects.

I tried this:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Login loginClass = new Login();
        int userType = loginClass.returnUserType();
    }
}
```

But it says Login does not contain a definition for `returnUserType`.

The class is a public partial class `Login:System.Web.UI.Page` with other functions inside and has this

```
public int returnUserType()
{
   try
   {
      return userType;
   }
   catch
   {
      Response.Write("UserType failed to be returned.");
      return 9;
   }
 }
```

I know I should probably be using Identity or Membership but I can't get them to run for some reason.

Comment: You can move it to a common master page.

Comment: It has the same problem there.

Comment: Why don't you create a separate class with function returnUserType and let any page/class to call.

Comment: How does the `userType` get populated?

Comment: I could make a separate class but shouldn't that class work anyway? Is it because it's a Page?
userType is just an int variable which gets a copy from a database source.

Answer (score 0):

Create a base Page and inherit all your pages from it, so the code should look like this

```
public class BasePage:System.Web.UI.Page
{
   public int returnUserType()
   {
     try
     {
       return userType;
     }
     catch
     {
       Response.Write("UserType failed to be returned.");
       return 9;
     } 
  }
}

public partial class _Default : BasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int userType = returnUserType();
    }
}
```